# Wix - getting info from a Browse dialog for display in an Edit (not PathEdit) box?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building an installer where a given page is asking for a directory. Unfortunately I'm not allowed (by the customer) to force an initial value into the entry (it must be blank), so using PathEdit is out--I have to use a raw Edit control.  I've added a Browse button that invokes the BrowseDlg, but the question is: how to show the value entered in the browse dialog?

I've seen recommendations of duplicating the original page, since I can't update the original textbox on the initial page. While that seems workable, how can I get to the 2nd copy of the page?  The button to open the Browse dialog invokes SpawnDialog. Doing it as a NewDialog looks really cheesy, and doesn't match the use of Browse dialog for the installation location, where it just pops up. But when the SpawnDialog returns, it just stays on the same page.  There's no condition I could come up with that would allow me to add a NewDialog to go to the 2nd page, or to any other page for that matter.

Any ideas on how to proceed, so I can show the entered Browse value?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a custom action and an edit box similar to this post. You can use a FolderBrowserDialog instead of the OpenFileDialog. It works for me, but upon a second install the field will be populated with the previous value.

http://community.saasgrid.com/developers/b/team/archive/2011/02/17/wix-managed-custom-actions-openfiledialog-example.aspx